# jQuery: force a user to select a value from the autocomplete suggest in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using this snippet to let the user choose from a list of cities, and insert them in a textarea, comma separated. That works.

I'd like to reach this objective: the user writes a part of the city name for searching it, similar to a combobox, but if he doesn't select one of the options and leaves the field, the inserted data should be erased.

So, briefly, I'd like to implement a sort of validation that prevents the users to fill the field with a string that is not a complete city name, before submitting the form.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

```js
jQuery( function() {
    var availableTags = [
"Agliè (TO)",
"Airasca (TO)",
//--- the other cities list ---
    ];
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }

    jQuery( 'textarea[data-wpt-id=wpcf-comuni-caldo],textarea[data-wpt-id=wpcf-comuni-freddo],textarea[data-wpt-id=wpcf-comuni-alta-potenza]' )
    //,input[name=wpv-wpcf-comuni-caldo],input[name=wpv-wpcf-comuni-freddo],input[name=wpv-wpcf-comuni-alta-potenza]
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === jQuery.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            jQuery( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
          // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
          response( jQuery.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        autoFill:true,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          terms.push( "" );
          this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          return false;
        }
      });
  } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself, as below.

```js
jQuery( function() {
var availableTags = [
"Agliè (TO)",
"Airasca (TO)",
//--- the other cities list ---
];
function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }

    var valoreAttuale = "";
    jQuery( 'textarea[data-wpt-id=wpcf-comuni-caldo],textarea[data-wpt-id=wpcf-comuni-freddo],textarea[data-wpt-id=wpcf-comuni-alta-potenza]' ).focus(function() { //al primo click nel campo, memorizzo le città attuali
      valoreAttuale = jQuery(this).val();
      console.log(valoreAttuale);
    });

    jQuery( 'textarea[data-wpt-id=wpcf-comuni-caldo],textarea[data-wpt-id=wpcf-comuni-freddo],textarea[data-wpt-id=wpcf-comuni-alta-potenza]' )
    //,input[name=wpv-wpcf-comuni-caldo],input[name=wpv-wpcf-comuni-freddo],input[name=wpv-wpcf-comuni-alta-potenza]
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === jQuery.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            jQuery( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
              event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
          // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
          response( jQuery.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        autoFill:true,
        change: function (event, ui)
        {
        if (!ui.label) { this.value = valoreAttuale; }
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          terms.push( "" );
          this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          valoreAttuale = jQuery(this).val();
          console.log(valoreAttuale);
          return false;
        }
      });
  } );
```

1. I save the current value (valoreAttuale) on focus;
2. If the user selects a suggested value, that will be added to the textarea and valoreAttuale gets updated; if the user types anything else (not in the array), jQuery restores the previous value of the field (valoreAttuale).